# Why Laravel Schedule with sub-minute interval skip next minute?

Tags: php, laravel, cron

In last versions of laravel 10 was added [sub-minute intervals](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#sub-minute-scheduled-tasks).
But i have strange behavior of runnig of cron task.
All works in Docker with docker-compose.
Cron works in separate from laravel container.

Crontab file:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/api/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/api/storage/logs/cron.log 2>&1
```

\App\Console\Kernel.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Jobs\OneC\SyncChangesFrom1C;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     */
    protected function commands(): void
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__ . '/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
        Log::debug('SCHEDULE RUN');
        $schedule->job(new SyncChangesFrom1C)->everyTenSeconds();
    }
}
```

**SyncChangesFrom1C** is a queued job. Now `handle` method is empty.

Logs of Laravel:

```
[2023-12-25 08:22:01] local.DEBUG: SCHEDULE RUN
[2023-12-25 08:24:00] local.DEBUG: SCHEDULE RUN
[2023-12-25 08:26:00] local.DEBUG: SCHEDULE RUN
[2023-12-25 08:28:00] local.DEBUG: SCHEDULE RUN
```

Logs of Cron:

```
2023-12-25 08:26:00 Running [App\Jobs\OneC\SyncChangesFrom1C] .... 14ms DONE
2023-12-25 08:26:10 Running [App\Jobs\OneC\SyncChangesFrom1C] ..... 6ms DONE
2023-12-25 08:26:20 Running [App\Jobs\OneC\SyncChangesFrom1C] .... 10ms DONE
2023-12-25 08:26:30 Running [App\Jobs\OneC\SyncChangesFrom1C] ..... 5ms DONE
2023-12-25 08:26:41 Running [App\Jobs\OneC\SyncChangesFrom1C] ..... 3ms DONE
2023-12-25 08:26:51 Running [App\Jobs\OneC\SyncChangesFrom1C] .... 15ms DONE

2023-12-25 08:28:00 Running [App\Jobs\OneC\SyncChangesFrom1C] .... 39ms DONE
2023-12-25 08:28:10 Running [App\Jobs\OneC\SyncChangesFrom1C] ..... 3ms DONE
2023-12-25 08:28:21 Running [App\Jobs\OneC\SyncChangesFrom1C] ..... 2ms DONE
2023-12-25 08:28:31 Running [App\Jobs\OneC\SyncChangesFrom1C] ..... 2ms DONE
2023-12-25 08:28:41 Running [App\Jobs\OneC\SyncChangesFrom1C] ..... 5ms DONE
2023-12-25 08:28:51 Running [App\Jobs\OneC\SyncChangesFrom1C] ..... 2ms DONE
```

If i`m change to everyMinute:

```php
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
        Log::debug('SCHEDULE RUN');
        $schedule->job(new SyncChangesFrom1C)->everyMinute();
    }
```

It work perfect, and run every minute.

Why it skip a minute before new run if used sub-minutes interval?

**UPD: I have submitted an [issue in Laravel github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/49488)**